# How to get Response Headers in Facebook Business SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-business-sdk

For a Project I need to check the `X-App-Usage` response Headers to throttle the amount of requests we are doing without running into the rate limiting.

How can I get the response headers? I can't find any documentation for this and no simple solution be diving into the source.
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk

```
<?php

use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;
use FacebookAds\Object\Post;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\CommentFields;

Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token, false);
$api = Api::instance();
$api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());

$post = new Post($postId);

$commentsRequest = $post->getComments(
    array(
        CommentFields::ID,
        CommentFields::FROM,
        CommentFields::MESSAGE
    ),
    array(
        'limit' => 500
    ),
    true
);        // returns FacebookAds\ApiRequest

$cursor = $commentsRequest->execute(); // returns FacebookAds\Cursor
$cursor->setUseImplicitFetch(true);

foreach ($cursor as $comment) {
    // returns an instance of FacebookAds\Object\Comment
    // doing some stuff with the comments
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk/blob/894bc3816db7bfac24cb5384293fbb8c0d1ff13d/src/FacebookAds/Http/Response.php#L85 …?

Comment: I found this, but there is no way to get the FacebookAds\Http\Request Object. Also those seem to be the Request Headers, not the Response Headers.

Comment: So what objects are you actually workinjg with then? Show some code.

Comment: @CBroe i updated the question and added a code example.

Comment: `FacebookAds\Cursor` allows you to get the `response` object via a method call, headers should probably be available via that then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution to my problem.
I can get the response and headers from the `Cursor` object via `$cursor->getLastResponse()->getHeaders())`.